# How to make a dictionary retain its sort order?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, ordereddictionary

```
def positive(self):
    total = {}
    final = {}
    for word in envir:
        for i in self.lst:
            if word in i:
                if word in total:
                    total[word] += 1
                else:
                    total[word] = 1
    final = sorted(total, reverse = True)

    return total
```

This returns

```
{'climate': 10, 'ecosystem': 1, 'energy': 6, 'human': 1, 'world': 2, 'renewable': 2, 'native': 2}
```

I want to get this dictionary back to a dictionary that is in order. How do you I sort it and return a dictionary?

Comment: Why do you want to sort a dictionary? You can't sort a dictionary.

Comment: Use [```collections.OrderedDict```](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict),  I thnk in Python 3.6 *normal* dictionaries become ordered.

Comment: Did you want to return final?

Comment: Python does in fact have an OrderedDict. However it can't be sorted by arbitrary function, it only retains its original insertion order. A more complicated related question: [How to sort OrderedDict in OrderedDict - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8031418/how-to-sort-ordereddict-in-ordereddict-python)?

Comment: Related: @JacquesdeHooge's answer to [Sorting OrderedDict not working](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/38796446/revisions)

Answer (score 1):

An ordered dictionary would get you what you need

```
from collections import OrderedDict
```

If you want to order your items in lexicographic order, then do the following

```
d1 = {'climate': 10, 'ecosystem': 1, 'energy': 6, 'human': 1, 'world': 2, 'renewable': 2, 'native': 2}
od = OrderedDict(sorted(d1.items(), key=lambda t: t[0]))
```

Contents of `od`:

```
OrderedDict([('climate', 10),
             ('ecosystem', 1),
             ('energy', 6),
             ('human', 1),
             ('native', 2),
             ('renewable', 2),
             ('world', 2)])
```

If  you want to specify exactly which order you want your dictionary, then store them as tuples and store them in that order.

```
t1 = [('climate',10), ('ecosystem', 1), ('energy',6), ('human', 1), ('world', 2), ('renewable', 2), ('native', 2)]
od = OrderedDict()

for (key, value) in t1:
    od[key] = value
```

`od` is now

```
OrderedDict([('climate', 10),
             ('ecosystem', 1),
             ('energy', 6),
             ('human', 1),
             ('world', 2),
             ('renewable', 2),
             ('native', 2)])
```

In use, it is just like a normal dictionary, but with its internal contents' order specified.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries in Python have no explicit order (except in 3.6). There is no property of 'order' in a hash table. To preserve order in Python, use a list of tuples:

`unordered = (('climate', 10,), ('ecosystem', 1))  # etc`

Calling `sorted(unordered)` on the above will give it back with the 'key' being the first item in each individual tuple. You do not need to provide any other arguments to `sorted()` in this case.

To iterate, use `for x, y in z:` where `z` is the list.

Comment: The OP is clearly looking for `collections.OrderedDict`. Telling them that `dict` doesn't support key order isn't helpful.